# The meaning of a solution to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What exactly do we mean when we say a differential equation is solvable? Is there a rigorous definition of what solvable means in the context of differential equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider the simplest case of a differential equation. That is, an **O**rdinary **D**ifferential **E**quation (ODE).

This is an equation involving functions (of one independent variable), their derivatives, and the variable itself.

One example would be the [Duffing Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duffing_equation):

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + \delta\frac{dx}{dt} + \alpha x + \beta x^3 = \gamma cos(\omega t)$$

where the numbers $\delta, \alpha, \beta, \gamma$ and $\omega$ are given constants.

Here, the unknown is a **function**, specifically $x(t)$.

To solve a Differential Equation means to find all the functions that satisfy it. Each of these functions is then called a **solution** to the differential equation.

We often speak of solutions on a given interval. In other words, we may accept that a function is a solution to a DE for values of its independent variable on some interval, even if it fails to satisfy the equation for values in other intervals.

The vast majority of differential equations are not solvable analytically. We have to resort to numerical methods to find approximate solutions.

However, a differential equation may be solvable even if we can't find exact solutions to it. There are, for example, theorems that guarantee the existence of solutions to a differential equation, even though they give no insight into what those solutions might be.

Finally, note that the equations that students typically solve in high school have *numbers* as their solutions. This is a key distinction between algebraic equations (as they are often called) and differential equations. When solving a DE, you are always looking to find a function, or a set of functions.

Comment: yes but what does a function mean in this context? what is the most fundamental idea? Is it just an expression of the form x(t)= something? or does it mean there is an integral curve corredposnding to the differential equation whether or not I can express it as a function?

Comment: Yes, you can think of a solution as an integral curve. That does not mean that there will be an elementary representation of that solution. In fact in most cases there won't be. This is what I meant when I said that solutions often *exist*, even if we can't express them in the form x(t) = something.

Comment: thank you! that helped a lot

Comment: @ArisMercier caution about the solution since there are also differential equations where uniqueness of solutions are not hold, so you can have multiple solutions even with same initial conditions: as example, the issues related with the Norton's Dome equation, and even relaxations of the meaning of what is a solution in stochastic differential equations... a "differential equation" , "integrable", and a "solution" could be quite wide concepts about its meaning giving some contexts in math.

Answer (score -1):

In high school, when you solve equations, you are typically solving equations of the form $f(x)=0,$ where $x$ is some quantity belonging to a specific mathematical structure, usually the rational numbers $(\mathbb{Q}),$ real numbers $(\mathbb{R}),$ or complex numbers $(\mathbb{C}).$ What does it mean to solve the above equation? Well, for some values of $x$ in the structure in question, $f(x)=0$ may be false, and for others, it may be true. Solving the equation means to find the values for which the equation is true.

Solving a differential equation is a similar concept, but rather than finding what *real numbers* make an equation true, you are trying to find what *functions of real numbers* make the equation true. This does raise a question, though: what is a function? And this is a question you asked in the comments at some point. To be frank, this is a separate question, and so I will not go into detail here in my answer. But a function is, roughly speaking, a set of ordered pairs where the output of the pair is unique for any input. And in the case of differential functions, we only focus on functions that can be differentiated.